# Finding point of intersection of two parametric equations

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Given the following two parametric equations:

$$x = t^2$$
$$y = t^3 -t$$

how can I find the points of where those two lines intersect?
I am asked to find the area of the enclosed region and so far I got
the integral figured out now I just need the limits of integration
which should be where these two lines meet, right?

Comment: Are you sure that you want a *parametric* equation.  Note that $\{x, y\} = \{t^2, t^3 - t\}$ describes a **single** curve.

Comment: ...or are you interested in looking at the region in the plane between the graphs of the two functions $y_1 = t^2$ and $y_2 = t^3 - t$?  (It's a bit confusing to call one of these functions $x$ if they're both functions to be graphed on the same set of axes.)

Comment: yes, the parametric equation describes a single curve in the x,y plane

Comment: So, you're looking for the point(s) where the curve intersects *itself?*

Comment: yes, but when I plotted the graph I got the points 0 and 1 as my bounds but that did not work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $t_1$ and $t_2$ are the parameters of a self-intersection point.  In other words,
$$
t_1^2 = t_2^2 \qquad \text{and} \qquad t_1^3 - t_1 = t_2^3 - t_2.
$$
The first equation (equating the $x$-coordinates) shows that $t_2 = \pm t_1$, so if we want distinct parameters
$$
t_2 = -t_1.
$$
Then, the second equation (equating the $y$-coordinates) becomes
$$
\begin{align}
t_1^3 - t_1 &= \left( -t_1 \right)^3 - \left( -t_1 \right) \\
&= - t_1^3 + t_1 \\
&= - \left( t_1^3 - t_1 \right),
\end{align}
$$
which shows that
$$
0 = 2(t_1^3 - t_1) = 2t_1(t_1 - 1)(t_1 + 1).
$$
Hence, $t_1 = \pm 1$ with $t_2 = - t_1 = \mp 1$.  Therefore, the self-intersection point is
$$
(x, y) = (1, 0).
$$